# How to connect to mysql properly in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database-connection

what i trying to do here is query to mysql database, but when i execute my query, it just loading forever, no error untill it timed out, how to solve this? below is my db.js code :

Db.js :

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var settings = require("../settings");

    exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback) {
        var conn = new mysql.createConnection(settings.dbConfig);
        conn.connect(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err + "1");
                return;
            }

            console.log(conn.log + "2");
        })

};
```

and here is my bassCtrl.js :

```
var db = require("../core/db");
var httpMsgs = require("../core/httpMsgs");

    exports.get_user = function(req, resp) {


        db.executeSql("select * from mst_user", function(data, err) {
            console.log("in controller");
            if (err) {
                httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
            } else {
                httpMsgs.sendJson(req, resp, data);
            };
        });
};
```

and here is my routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bassCtrl = require("../controllers/bassCtrl");
var httpMsgs = require("../core/httpMsgs");
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = function(app, express) {
    var router = express();

    router.route('/get_user').get(bassCtrl.get_user);


return router;
};
```

below is my HttpMsgs.js :

```
var settings = require("../settings");

exports.show500 = function(req, resp, err) {
    if (settings.httpMsgsFormat === 'HTML') {
        resp.writeHead(500, "Internal Error occuared", {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        resp.write("<html><head><title>500</title></head><body>500: Internal Error. Details: " + err + "</body></html>");
    } else {
        resp.writeHead(500, "Internal Error occuared", {"Content-Type":"application/json"});
        resp.write(JSON.stringify({ data: "Error occurred: " + err }));
    }
    resp.end();
}

exports.sendJson = function(req, resp, data) {
    resp.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"application/json"});
    if (data) {
        resp.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    resp.end();
}

exports.show405 = function(req, resp) {
    if (settings.httpMsgsFormat === 'HTML') {
        resp.writeHead(405, "Method not supported", {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        resp.write("<html><head><title>405</title></head><body>405: Method not supported.</body></html>");
    } else {
        resp.writeHead(405, "Method not supported", {"Content-Type":"application/json"});
        resp.write(JSON.stringify({ data: "Method not supported"}));
    }
    resp.end();
}

exports.show413 = function(req, resp) {
    if (settings.httpMsgsFormat === 'HTML') {
        resp.writeHead(404, "Resource not found", {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        resp.write("<html><head><title>413</title></head><body>404: Resource not found.</body></html>");
    } else {
        resp.writeHead(404, "Resource not found", {"Content-Type":"application/json"});
        resp.write(JSON.stringify({ data: "Resource not found"}));
    }
    resp.end();
}

exports.show413 = function(req, resp) {
    if (settings.httpMsgsFormat === 'HTML') {
        resp.writeHead(413, "Request Entity Too Large", {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        resp.write("<html><head><title>413</title></head><body>413: Request Entity Too Large.</body></html>");
    } else {
        resp.writeHead(413, "Request Entity Too Large", {"Content-Type":"application/json"});
        resp.write(JSON.stringify({ data: "Request Entity Too Large"}));
    }
    resp.end();
}

exports.send200 = function(req, resp) {
    resp.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"application/json"});
    resp.write(JSON.stringify(
        {status: "success", code: 200}
    ));
    resp.end();
}

exports.showHome = function(req, resp) {
    if (settings.httpMsgsFormat === 'HTML') {
        resp.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        resp.write("<html><head><title>200</title></head><body>Your server connected dude ! :)</body></html>");
    } else {
        resp.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"application/json"});
        resp.write(JSON.stringify(
            {status: "Your server connected dude ! :)"}
        ));
    }
    resp.end();
}
```

and here is my settings.js :

```
exports.dbConfig = {
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    host: "localhost",
    database: "zouk"
};

exports.httpMsgsFormat = "json";
```

when i trigger localhost:5000/get_user, it just loading till it timed out, and my console.log print this line `console.log(connection.log + "2");` with undefined as the value. is there something i missing?

wait a minute, why my question rated minus?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't execute your query in Db.js file, and your code don't call the callback too, that's why it run until timeout.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : ***,
  user     : ***,
  password : ***,
  database : ***,
});

connection.connect();

connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
  //your callback go here.
  // callback(rows);//pass whatever you need in.
});

connection.end();
```

Plus, your controller have no require for `httpMsgs`. I think it should have.

Comment: yes, i already execute my db.js file, i just undate my controller file named bassCtrl.js. I execute it at this line db.executeSql("select * from mst_user", function(err, rows, fields)

Comment: You can try skip using `httpMsgs` and use resp right the way. Use `console.log` in each step of your process to observe.